# 500 (Internal Server Error) ao definir ação como [ChildActionOnly]

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Quero bloquear url do partialview através url usando `[ChildActionOnly]`.

Enfrento problema, segue código:

**HTML:**

```
<li style="cursor:pointer"><a id="button_id">Criar</a></li>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#button_id").click(function () {
    $("#conteudoModal").load("@Url.Action("MinhaAcao", "Controller")", function () {
        $('#minhaModal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
[ChildActionOnly] // <----- Aqui
public ActionResult MinhaAcao()
{
    var model = new Model();


    return PartialView(model);
}
```

Sem `[ChildActionOnly]` o modal abre normal e com url partialview.

Com `[ChildActionOnly]`, ao clicar no botão "Criar", recebo mensagem de erro:

> Detalhes da Exceção: System.InvalidOperationException: A ação
>   'MinhaAcao' é acessível apenas para uma solicitação filha.

Alguma solução ?

Comment: Qual é a mensagem de erro?

Comment: @LINQ Erro 500 pelo que entendi.

Comment: @Aline **500** não é mensagem de erro, esse código não diz absolutamente nada. Ele é somente um número que identifica o tipo da resposta HTTP, onde, semanticamente, quer dizer que houve um erro do lado do servidor. Aplicações ASP.NET geralmente devolvem uma resposta 500 quando ocorreu uma exceção, se ocorreu uma exceção existe uma mensagem e um _stacktrace_.

Comment: @LINQ, relaxa. Se eu tiver algum problema de rota ou permissão, vai retornar erro 500 e nenhuma outra informação. É o que entendi que está acontecendo com ele. Se você sabe como prover uma informação mais detalhada qndo ela não está no console, responda, por gentileza, porque eu também quero saber. =T

Comment: @Aline Não entendi o "relaxa". Sobre a mensagem de erro: você está enganada, naturalmente isso não vai acontecer. O erro 500 sempre vai devolver uma página com as informações que originaram a exceção. Se a chamada for feita via JavaScript é possível ver a página na aba _network_ do _browser_.

Comment: @LINQ, é verdade. Tu tem razão. Aparece a página e tudo o mais. E o relaxa foi só força de expressão.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acontece que *actions* marcadas com o atributo [**`[ChildActionOnly]`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.childactiononlyattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) só podem ser chamadas como um método "filho" de dentro de uma *view*, usando os métodos de extensão [`Html.Action()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.action(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String)) ou [`Html.RenderAction()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.renderaction(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.RenderAction(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String)).

O método `load`, provavelmente, faz uma requisição GET pro servidor, via XMLHttpRequest. Ou seja, você está tentando fazer a chamada da *action* justamente da maneira que está tentando bloquear usando este atributo.

A única saída é remover este atributo.

Se quiseres bloquear o usuário de ver o conteúdo da *partial view* pelo browser, pode fazer uma requisição no *server-side* usando `Request.IsAjaxRequest()`.

Algo como:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MinhaAcao()
{
    if(!Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        return HttpNotFound();   

    return PartialView();
}
```

Comment: LINQ, Existe outra forma de bloquear ?

Comment: Tem algumas maneiras, precisa ver o que você acha melhor. Dá pra injetar o código da modal ao carregar a página e depois abrir a modal usando o código que já existe na página, isto é, se não for necessário nenhum processamento do lado do servidor. Este modal é do _bootstrap_?

Comment: sim é do bootstrap.

Comment: Então acho que essa é uma saída viável. Carregar o HTML da partial na view principal e chamar a modal a partir deste código. Não sei como se faz isso porque muito pouco conheço do _bootstrap_, mas acho que deu pra entender a ideia principal.

Comment: Exemplo: `if (Request.IsAjaxRequest() == false) { return HttpNotFound();}`

Comment: @MatheusMiranda Editei